# 3D Touch doesn't in CollectionView

Tags: swift, collectionview, 3dtouch

I created a soundboard and I would like when you long push on the tile (CollectionView Cell) that become a 3D Touch popup with the text of the tile.

I have a ViewCollection with the storyboard ID 'tilePreview'. And the below code, but the 3D touch doesn't.

What do I wrong? Can anybody help me?

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate  {

    @IBOutlet var soundBoard: UICollectionView!

    var list = [String]()
    var buttonOn: Bool = true

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == UIForceTouchCapability.available {
            registerForPreviewing(with: self, sourceView: collectionView!)
        }
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> MyCollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

        let tileText = list[indexPath.row]

        cell.cellTitle.text = tileText

        return cell
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        Speak(currentTitle: list[indexPath.row])
    }

    // MARK: - Preview tile
    func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {

        guard let indexPath = collectionView?.indexPathForItem(at: location) else { return nil }
        guard let cell = collectionView?.cellForItem(at: indexPath) else { return nil }
        guard let detailVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tilePreview") as? DetailViewController else { return nil }
        previewingContext.sourceRect = cell.frame

        return detailVC
    }

    func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, commit viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController) {

        show(viewControllerToCommit, sender: self)

    }


}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force touch on UICollectionView inside of UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41498963/force-touch-on-uicollectionview-inside-of-uitableviewcell)

Comment: You need to register each collectionView, not the larger object. Do that inside `cellForItemAt`, and see linked post.

Comment: Why did you [roll back the edit nathan made](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45261272/revisions)? It looks to me like it significantly clarified your post by improving the grammar. I don't see anywhere where he changed the meaning of your question. What was it that you didn't like? Or was it an accident?

Answer (score 1):

**1) in viewDidLoad check 3D Touch is available or not**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //3D touch
    if(traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .available){
        registerForPreviewing(with: self, sourceView: view)
    }
}
```

**2) Delegate method for 3D touch**

```
//3D Touch delegate method
extension PostViewController : UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate {
    @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, commit viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController) {
        self.navigationController?.show(viewControllerToCommit, sender: self)
    }

    @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {
        let locationCell : CGPoint = self.collectionView.convert(location, from: self.view)

        guard let indexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPathForItem(at: locationCell) else {
            print(locationCell)
            print("Cell Not found")
            return nil
        }

        print("indexPath.row :: \(indexPath.row)")
        guard let cell = self.collectionView?.cellForItem(at: indexPath) else { return nil }

        let didSelectProduct : ProductDM = self.products[indexPath.row]
        let destination: ProductDetailsViewController = UIStoryboard(storyboard: .main).instantiateViewController()
        destination.selectedProduct = didSelectProduct
        //destination.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 300)

        previewingContext.sourceRect = self.collectionView.convert(cell.frame, to: self.collectionView.superview)
        return destination
    }
}
```